# Using the interpolation to find some data

Tags: statistics

[image]

For part d of this question i want to know what does the sentence "one standard deviation of the means" mean because it is not clear for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within one standard deviation of the mean is interval centered on the mean  with length equal to two standard deviations. So if the mean is $\sigma$ and the deviation is $\tau$ then this is $[\sigma - \tau, \sigma + \tau]$.

Comment: Can i do it using the interpolation like the calculation of the median ? @CyclotomicField